# Hibernate create a copy of entity in listener

Tags: java, hibernate, listener

In my application I have an instance of **A**, when I update **Ai**, I want to create a *copy of Ai* with all previous values and insert that.

To do this work, I made a **PreUpdateEventListener** and in the onPreUpdate method, I want to create that clone, and then save it as a new instance, so assign Id:0 and then treat it as a new insertion.

To do that, I've:

1. from the SessionFactory, I opened a new Session
2. from that new session, using the **Ai** identifier, I've *loaded* the instance with previous state
3. I closed the newly created session
4. then I created a new instance, the clone, and then I copied into all the values treating associations so they could be treated as new ones
5. then I saved the new instance, the clone, in the current session

Everything seems to work, but when my code calls the flush (the caller code) I get a *fantastic*:

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: collection [null] was not processed by flush()
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionEntry.postFlush(CollectionEntry.java:214)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.postFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:369)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
at it.xyxyx.test.DaoBaseTest.FlushUnitOfWork(DaoBaseTest.java:28)
at it.xyxyx.service.dao.PlanDaoTest.testCan_query_for_plan_audit_with_plan_group_id(PlanDaoTest.java:344)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Any help is apprechiated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why dont you use http://envers.jboss.org/ ??

Comment: Because I won't an audit trail, I need to replicate in the same table an entire structure cloning first child relationships selectively, if it was so simple I'd used envers as first choiche! Thanks anyway